# C++ Read floats from file into dynamic table

Tags: c++, file, dynamic, binary

I need to read one line after another of the data from .csv file.
Line length may vary so I want to use the dynamic structure but I don't know how.
There are only floats, no mixed types. I can use only standard libraries.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
ifstream obraz;

obraz.open("POP_OCT.csv", ios::binary);

if(!obraz)
    cerr<<"couldn't open file"<<endl;
float length; //actually this one comes from the file

 while( !obraz.eof() ) // read lines
 {
    //read data from the verse to line[]
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
        {
        obraz>>line[i];
        obraz.seekg(+1, ios_base::cur);
        }
  obraz.close()
  return 0;
}
```

This is how I do it with normal table but it's size is defined as  500. If I read in another file length may be different so how to use dynamic table here?

Comment: You didn't mention what the problem is when you used your methods.

Comment: Consider using std::getline in combination with std::string to read line by line. And CSV files are not binary files, they are text files (although there is no difference between binary and text on UNIX/Linux).

Comment: I didn't know getline works with files read binary ( I mean use of  ios::binary).

Comment: `float` for `length`?

Comment: @Artur If your files is a comma-separated-value file, then open it at text, not as binary. Such files are simple text files.

Comment: @vsoftco    It's a project that I have to do for my study and my teacher told me to use (ios::binary).

Comment: @LogicStuff It is float. I read all the data from header of the file in floats. Float has different size than int, so if float works I don't want to change it.